# Load static resource in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to make page using `thymeleaf`. But I have some problem with the static files. I've investigated questions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869267/loading-static-resources-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541839/static-resources-using-spring-and-thymeleaf),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918732/not-loading-static-resources-in-spring-boot-thymeleaf-and-angularjs-app)) with similar problem, but it didn't help me.

I use `Spring Boot` framework in the application.
My files look like:
[image]

**test.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <script src="js/test.js" th:src="@{/test.js}"/>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="testFunction('test value')">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function testFunction(test) {
    console.log(test);
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```

And problem, when I load `test.html` file with javascript not loaded.

```
@GetMapping(value = "web/test")
public String getTestHtmlPage() {
    return "test";
}
```

[image]

`/api/v1` is a configuration in `application.properties => server.servlet-path=/api/v1`

What do I do wrong? Can you help me?

Thanks all!

Comment: You didn't include the error for test.js... Is it a 404? The actual path should just be `test.js` not `js/test.js`

Comment: Yes, it is 404 error. When I changed to `<script src="test.js" th:href="@{/test.js}"/>` response status is 200, but in console appear a new error `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/web/test.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` What is it mean?

Comment: I don't know Thymeleaf, but looking at the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) indicates `th:href` applies to HTML content. Javascript is not HTML, so you should remove `th:href` and change `src` to `th:src` I guess.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, ohh, yes, it's silly error, I changed to `th:src` i now receive 404 error, request to file look as `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/web/js/test.js`. I don't have this endpoint.

Comment: It's the same as your original error...

Comment: why the href? Also the path you are using is relative, have you tried `<script th:src="@{/js/test.js}"></script>`? It works for me regardless of the controller url

Comment: @Paizo That won't work due to the resource locations. If the resource location is mapped to `classpath:/static/` then `/js/test.js` will work. With the way it's configured, `/js/test.js` looks in `/js/js/test.js`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a better understanding of `registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");`

I wrote a more thorough [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162110/spring-4-static-content-like-css-js-brings-error-405-request-method-get-not-su/42168185#42168185) that discusses invalid resource location mappings. It didn't receive any upvotes, so I hope it's not terrible. :-)

In short, with the way you're mapping `classpath:/static/js/`, and then accessing, `/js/test.js`, you're telling Spring to look in `/static/js/js/test.js`.

What you probably want is `classpath:/static/`. In that case, when you try to access `/js/test.js`, it's looking in  `/static/js/test.js` for the file instead.

As for Thymeleaf, I've never used it, but docs indicate you should load scripts with `th:src` instead of `th:href`. `th:href` appears to only be for HTML content.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried to make change according to your answer. I found problem in source. I use property `server.servlet-path` in the `application.properties`. The `server.servlet-path` mean path to controller and equals `/api/v1`. When did I make request without `server.servlet-path` property all works fine (url `http://localhost:8080/css/main.css`). If do  request with `server.servlet-path` property then I will receive 404 error (url the same `server.servlet-path` property, but **I think it must be changed**). Maybe do you know? I can't find solution..

Comment: I was added `api/v1` to `th:href` and `th:src` and **it work**. Can I make it other way? When `server.servlet-path` will be change I also must to change path in the all `.html` files :-(

Comment: I'm not really sure, as I have no experience with Thymeleaf. I'd suggest looking into the docs to find out how `th:href` and `th:src` resolve paths. It seems like they're not aware of the servlet-path. There's probably a setting so Thymeleaf is aware of the context root you can set.